# How a can open programmaticly LibreOffice in modal mode in separate process

Tags: linux, windows, libreoffice, openoffice.org

How a can open programmaticly LibreOffice in modal mode in separate process, like winword.exe /w?

under windows/linux

Didn't find anything...

Comment: do you know how to open winword programmatically?

Comment: Yep, CreateProcess( NULL, "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE\" \"filename.docx" /w /x", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL     , NULL, NULL, &StartInfo, &ProcInfo); WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hThread, INFINITE);

Comment: So use this knowledge to open LibreOffice.

Comment: LibreOffice have "/x /f" command line parameters?